# QML: Failure accessing properties with error "Unable to assign [undefined] to "

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt5.15

I have this simple QML files:

`qml/Constants.qml`:

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.15

QtObject {
    readonly property int width: 1920
    readonly property int height: 1080

    readonly property color bgColor: "#c2c2c2"
}
```

`qml/MainMenu.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle {
    id: mainMenu
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height
    visible: true
    color: Constants.bgColor
    border.color: "#ffffff"
    clip: false
}
```

and the main window in `qml/main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    id: root
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height

    visible: true

    StackView {
        id: stack
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: MainMenu {}
    }
}
```

I build the resources using this `resources.qrc` with `rcc`:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
        <qresource prefix="/mbh">
                <file alias="Constants.qml">qml/Constants.qml</file>
                <file alias="main.qml">qml/main.qml</file>
                <file alias="MainMenu.qml">qml/MainMenu.qml</file>
        </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And execute the `main.qml` using a simple `main.cpp` that simply load and execute `qml/main.qml`.
During execution I have these errors:

```
qrc:/mbh/main.qml:8:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
qrc:/mbh/main.qml:7:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to int
qrc:/mbh/MainMenu.qml:9:5: Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
```

Why `main.qml` is not able to get `Constants.width` and `Constants.height`, but `MainMenu.qml` is (apparently) able to obtain these 2 values?
And why `MainMenu.qml` is not able to obtain `Constants.bgColor`?

NOTE: Qt version is 5.15.2

Thanks

Comment: Did you try adding this line to the top of your source files: `import "."`? I remember there being an issue with always needing to specify the path for singletons even if it was in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but nothing change, I have the same error about undefined values.
The include should be fine, because I don't have any error about the creation of `MainMenu`.

Comment: Did you add a qmldir file? QML's rules for singletons seem unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: You're right, I've investigated a bit and seems that the problem is that the singleton is not "initializated". I've put `Constants.qml` into a module and created a `qmldir` file (as you suggested) and this fix the problem. I don't like too much having a module for one single generic file, so I'm going to search how to "initialize" the signleton manually in `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution is

1. Add `qmlRegisterSingletonType()` to `main.cpp`:

   ```cpp
   qmlRegisterSingletonType(
       QUrl("qrc:/your/prefix/to/Constants.qml"),
       "ConstantsModule",
       1, 0,
       "Constants");
   ```
2. Do `import ConstantsModule 1.0` anywhere you use `Constants`.

---

##### main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    // !!! THIS LINE, the rest are default Qt template lines
    // WARNING use your own qrc prefix for Constants.qml
    qmlRegisterSingletonType(
                QUrl("qrc:/stackoverflow4/Constants.qml"),
                "ConstantsModule",
                1, 0,
                "Constants");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/stackoverflow4/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

##### main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

import ConstantsModule 1.0 // !!! THIS LINE

Window {
    id: root
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height

    visible: true

    StackView {
        id: stack
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: MainMenu{}
    }
}
```

##### Constants.qml

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.15

QtObject {
    readonly property int width: 1920
    readonly property int height: 1080
    readonly property color bgColor: "#c2c2c2"
}
```

##### MainMenu.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

import ConstantsModule 1.0 // !!! THIS LINE

Rectangle {
    id: mainMenu
    width: Constants.width
    height: Constants.height
    visible: true
    color: Constants.bgColor
    border.color: "#ffffff"
    clip: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [JarMan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7427152/jarman) the singleton shall be correctly initialized.

It is enough to create a `qmldir` file (there is no need to create a module), `qml/qmldir`:

```
singleton Constants 1.0 Constants.qml
```

And add the `qmldir` file to the list of resources in `resources.qrc`:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
        <qresource prefix="/mbh">
                <file alias="qmldir">qml/qmldir</file>
...
```